# Does slicing bigger image (2 MB~5 MB) helpful for loading sliced images on web for better appeal

Tags: image, http, web, httprequest, performance-testing

Well I am struggling between best practice and nice to have feature and need your opinion before embarking on fruit(less/full) endeavor.

To improve server performance its been suggested to have less server calls. But then I dislike the part where a big file takes a long time to load. I would rather prefer to load file in chunks for better appeal (like google map loads in layer/tiles).

What is the take of community on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its better you Use CDN (Content Delivery Network) for static images rendering in your webpage, which should be hosted in other Server or Cloud environment.

You'll surely see the performnace improvement.

Thanks